# Issue with uploading a file through the multer package

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I'm using `multer` to upload a file through `node.js`.
The file object that is sent from our FE is:

```
file: FileList
    0: File
    lastModified: 1647806297845
    lastModifiedDate: Sun Mar 20 2022 21:58:17 GMT+0200
    name: "Example Docx.docx"
    size: 12143
    type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    webkitRelativePath: "
```

With the input's `name` attribute `'cv'`.
My usage of `multer` is:

```
const uploadSingleFile = multer.single('cv');

uploadSingleFile(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        next(err);
    }
    next();
});
```

Yet I don't get any file in `req.file`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue wad resolved by sending `file[0]` to `multer`.

It appears it's not designed to handle the `FileList` object in the scanario above.